# There is no document formatter for 'qsharp'-files installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, auto-indent, q#

I've recently started using Q# on VS Code.

When I Press, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, I get the error about a missing document formatter.
I've tried searching the extensions and settings, but I'm unable to find one that does the job (There is an extension which provides syntax highlighting, but it doesn't seem to do formatting though) :'(.

I understand that Q# is a new language and as such is not a very popular one. So, all I want is to auto-indent using the same rules as C# for now. Is there a way I can get away with using the same formatter that VS Code uses for C# to indent?

I've searched the settings for some simple setting to fill up or toggle but found none. 
I'm very confused about the whole settings.json thing and only enabled vim keybindings with great difficulty, so I can't really say I've played around with it.

UPDATE:

Basically, what I want to do is something like this in the settings.json file:

```
if (filetype == 'qs'){
    editor.formattype = 'C#';
}
```

Comment: Well, you could switch the language mode of the file to C#... But chances are a C# formatter wouldn't even understand Q# syntax.

Answer (score 2):

We're still working on integrating a document formatter into the vs code extension. For the time being, you could try to run the following from the command line:

`dotnet msbuild /t:qsharpformat`

That will format all the .qs files in the current project. The formatter expects the Q# files to compile correctly, or things might not work properly. The changes are done in-place, the original files are copied into a folder inside `obj\qsharp\.backup.` in case you want to roll back the changes.

Hope this helps.